# How to achieve MongoDB DBObject cascading dot notation via osinka.subset

Tags: mongodb, scala, syntax, subset

As a Subset user, I'd like to produce a Query containing two dots but I don’t get it done on the fly. Let me enhance your BlogPost example http://osinka.github.com/subset/Subset+Query.html to demonstrate what I want to achieve even if it doesn’t make sense this way:

```scala
case class SubComment(subText: String)
case class Comment(by: String, votes: Int, text: SubComment)
case class BlogPost(title: String, comments: List[Comment])
object SubComment {
    val text = "text".fieldOf[String]
    implicit val writer = {
      def f(sub: SubComment): DBObject = (text -> sub.subText)
      ValueWriter(f _)
    }
  }
  object Comment {
    val by = "by".fieldOf[String]
    val votes = "votes".fieldOf[Int]
    val text = "text".fieldOf[SubComment]
  }
  object BlogPost {
    val title = "title".fieldOf[String]
    val comments = "comments".subset(Comment).of[List[Comment]]
  }
  val qComment = BlogPost.comments.where { _.by === "maria" }
  val qSubComment = BlogPost.comments.where {…? === "X"} // not yet working
```

How can I produce a DBObject `{ "comments.text.subText" : "X"}`?

Thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 1):

I am the author of **Subset**, so let me take a short detour and explain the details.

**Subset** (1.x) provides `Field[T]` to read and/or write fields to/from MongoDB documents (BSON). When you are reading or writing the field's contents, the only thing it must know is `T`. In other words, if you are working with BSON documents, you may declare all fields as `"fieldName".fieldOf[T]` whatever complex `T` is (e.g. list or subdocument)

Things get more complicated as soon as you need to create queries. Since MongoDB supports "dot notation", **Subset** needs to know the relationship between parent document and descendant fields. This goal gets accomplished when you declare fields as `"fieldName".subset(Obj).of[T]`. Here, `T` is actually not related to `Obj` at all. `T` is used by **Subset** to serialize/deserialize the field contents, while `Obj` is simply a container with fields, **Subset** will give it to you back when you invoke e.g. `where`

Let me demonstrate it by example. The only thing you need to change in your code is the following:

```
object Comment {
  ...
  val text = "text".subset(SubComment).of[SubComment]
}
```

and then you would write

```
scala> val q = BlogPost.comments.where { comment =>
     | comment.text.where { _.text === "X" }
     | }
q: com.osinka.subset.package.Query = Query{ "comments.text.text" : "X"}
```

Here, `comment` **is** `Comment` object.

---

When you know this, you are free to "cheat" and do the following:

```
val comments = "comments".subset(()).of[List[Comment]]
val commentText = "text".subset(()).of[SubComment]
val subcommentInnerField = "inner".fieldOf[String]

scala> comments.where { _ =>
     |   commentText.where { _ =>
     |     subcommentInnerField === "X"
     |   }
     | }
res1: com.osinka.subset.package.Query = Query{ "comments.text.inner" : "X"}
```

Here I'm giving `Unit` to `.subset()` method and thus we are getting `Unit` back in `where`. But it doesn't matter, since we know which fields to use inside `where` calls. This "cheating" is not as "safe" as keeping fields inside objects, but well demonstrates how things are wired.